The most efficient method of Laravel dependency reduction?
Controller->Service->Repository->Model->all()
I have a construction in laravel(11).  My code is as follows:
PostRepository.php
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Eloquent;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\IPost;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class PostRepository implements IPost
{
    protected $model;
    public function __construct(Post $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function all(): Collection
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }

    public function find(int $id): ?Post
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }
    //...etc
}

As you can see, this repo is dependent on the Post Model. If I want to change this model tomorrow, for example I want to add Redis etc., this will not be possible, and I don't think it is in accordance with solid principles.
1- Do I need to create an interface for each Eloquent model?
2- Won't binding them in AppserviceProvider break all these principles?
How do you solve this problem in your projects?

IMHO
There are two popular patterns: Active Record (implemented by Laravel models) and Data Mapper (the most popular implementation in PHP is Doctrine). You're trying to merge them, and I don't think it's a good idea. Active Record itself already violates the Single Responsibility Principle, but it's much simpler and convenient, especially for not very big projects. However, if your project is truly large and the drawbacks of Active Record outweigh its benefits, I would consider using Doctrine (and perhaps Symfony) instead of trying to implement Data Mapper on top of Active Record.

If you still want to develop your solution, then you need to create your own models that will contain only data and business rules. And your repositories should return these models, not eloquent. But keep in mind that with this approach, you will have to solve the mapping problems of data to your models yourself.

As far as I know, active record is one thing, robust policies are another. There is nothing I merge, there is standard service architecture. Laravel Eloquent ORM already implements active record, but I don't understand what this has to do with repository and service architecture and solid principles. I am trying to reduce dependencies.
My question is about Laravel and solid principles, nothing to do with Doctrine or Symfony or Data Mapper. Please answer according to the question template.

I'm trying to convey that there is no point in a repository that returns an Eloquent (active record) model, as this model already contains the logic for interacting with the database. You are creating an abstraction layer that will inevitably be leaky. For your repositories to make sense, you need to separate the models from the database interaction logic (which means it's no longer active record). Then the repositories can easily depend on the models without any interfaces, since the models will no longer depend on how and in which database you store the information.
